# Simulink - skipping results equals to zero at writing to file

Tags: matlab, simulink

The results are shown in this picture

[image]

I want to skip results equals to 0 and don't write to file. File looks like at this picture for now.

[image]

My question is what to do if I need file with results don't equals 0, the exact time and the data, for example

```
Time Data
1     25
5    -50
6     52
30     5
```

I tried to use if case blocks with block which compare result to Zero but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Enabled Subsystem.

Feed the signal that you want to save into its input port and the absolute value of your signal into the Enable port.  Any To File blocks in the subsystem will only write data when the subsystem is enabled, i.e. when your signal is non-zero.

Comment: Thank you for replay, I have tried this but with this result [link](http://i.imgur.com/5lt1mBd.png) Upper is the new signal and down is the old without enabled system, i need the signal in the old form but write to file only non zero results.

Comment: Sorry it is working i have to add the to file block after the Enabled system, and not IN. if i take it IN its working. Thank you